# Toast cancel is not working

Tags: android, android-widget, toast

When I searched about toast in stackoverflow I have found many things which were related to my problem.However none of them solved my problem. In my android app I am supposed to show many toasts after eachother.However when I try to do so, next toast waits for the current toast to finish. Even if I used cancel for toast , it seems to me it never works.Please offer me a exact solution.Thank you..

```
inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    backgForToast=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastbackground,backgForToast);
    textForToast = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);

    textForToast.setText(toastMessage);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, toastX2-90,toastY2-90);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    long delay = 500;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.cancel();
        }
    }, delay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `Toast` object with `Toast.makeText` before you can `cancel()` it.

Comment: I did it in onCreate method like that toast = new Toast(this);

Comment: OK, so you need to call `toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);` (or something like that) before you call `cancel()`.

Comment: But i am using custom toast... I inflate a view in toast

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example cancelling a `Toast`:

```
Toast mytoast;
mytoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Jorgesys was here!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mytoast.show();
....
....
....
if(CancelToast){
  mytoast.cancel();   //Cancelling the toast!.
}
```